# Law of double complement vs principle of duality for sets (Discrete Math)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

### Logical Questions:

> Will the law of double complement flip a union sign U to intersection sign ∩  ?
>
> If yes, does the law of double complement change the sign like the principle of duality for sets ?

### My Insight:

I am working with laws of set theory. In an example, I saw that the law of double complement changed A U B to A ∩ B. I thought I copied the notes down wrong at lecture, so some clarification would be great.

I also know that principle of duality changes union sign to intersection, and u to { }.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution + Logic:

After going through my notes, I realized that...

> Demorgan's law of a set separates a complement of a set A and B to two separate sets complement sets of A and B, but with their Union sign changed to intersection sign.

Comment: I thought this was coming from the law of double complement, but the answer is 'NO' , it is from the demorgan's law.